# How can I host my public GPG key on S3?

Tags: apt, amazon-s3, aptitude, keys, gpg

I've been packaging some proprietary software that runs on Raspbian into .deb files and hosting them in a private S3 bucket using a program called [deb-s3](https://github.com/krobertson/deb-s3). I also use a program called [apt-transport-s3](https://github.com/BashtonLtd/apt-transport-s3) which allows the individual devices to download the packages that I've published. But when I run `sudo apt-get update` I see the following warning:

> W: GPG error: s3://*bucket*.s3.amazonaws.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY *my-key-id*

I could install the GPG manually but I'd rather host it, so that I can just run `sudo apt-key add` and import it using the ID. Ideally, I'd love to just host that on S3 as well. The trouble is I have never set up a keyserver before so I don't know what sorts of files I'd need or what format they'd need to be in.

If I were to have a barebones keyserver with my GPG key in it, what would the file structure look like? And do you think I could replicate that on S3 and it would still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the key on a [static website bucket](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html), download it, and add the file with `apt-key add`. A couple lines of scripting, or use the Ansible apt_key module.

Or, submit the key to [your favorite keyserver](https://sks-keyservers.net/status/), and import with  `apt-key adv --recv-key`

Comment: But that gets to the heart of my question: what exactly is "the file"? What does it look like / how is it formatted?

Comment: ASCII armored PGP key export. Debian documentation mentions them, and many repos will have signing keys on their mirrors. https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/SetupWithReprepro